# Wrong atomikos state ABORTING after timeout in transaction

Tags: spring, atomikos

I am testing how atomikos solving timeout in transaction. I have 30s timeout in infinite read from db. After 30s I got this exception:

```
14:08:40.329 [Atomikos:4] WARN  c.a.icatch.imp.ActiveStateHandler - Transaction rob-app-b1c7b95a3b0efb82dfb516b04620a213154159609015500001 has timed out - rolling back...

2018-11-07 14:08:40.354 [pool-3-thread-1] WARN  c.a.jdbc.JdbcConnectionProxyHelper - Error enlisting in transaction - connection might be broken? Please check the logs for more information...
java.lang.IllegalStateException: wrong state: ABORTING
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CoordinatorImp.registerSynchronization(CoordinatorImp.java:420)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.TransactionStateHandler.registerSynchronization(TransactionStateHandler.java:129)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CompositeTransactionImp.registerSynchronization(CompositeTransactionImp.java:177)
    at com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy.enlist(AtomikosConnectionProxy.java:211)
    at com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy.invoke(AtomikosConnectionProxy.java:122)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy133.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
```

Why I got this error and no Atomikos Exception in AtomikosConnectionProxy during enlist method ?

```
 AtomikosSQLException.throwAtomikosSQLException("The transaction has timed out - try increasing the timeout if needed");
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is a timeout because your application has been using the transaction for too long. Try increasing the transaction timeout?